# NSUndoManager detect actual deletion of Core Data entities

Tags: ios, core-data, nsundomanager

I am looking for a way to know when a Core Data entity is **really** deleted from the data store.

I hooked up an `NSUndoManager` to my `NSManagedObjectContext` and so far everything is working fine.

### Current situation

I'm building an app that allows users to create `Room`s and add some pictures in each room. When the user wants to create a new room, I create an action in the NSUndoManager with the following code:

```
[[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] undoManager] beginUndoGrouping];
[[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] undoManager] setActionName:@"Create Room"];
```

and then `undo` when the user presses *cancel*. This causes all changes to be undone and the freshly created temporary `Room` object to be deleted.

A user then takes `Picture`s for this temporary `Room` object. I store the actual image on disk and the `filePath` as an `NSString` attribute in the `Picture` entity. When the user manually deletes a picture in a room, I delete the image from disk in the `prepareForDeletion:` method on `Picture`.

## Problem

Now imagine the situation where the user later opens the `Room` entity, deletes a `Picture` and then presses *cancel*. The `NSUndoManager` now undoes all the actions. When the user deleted the Picture, the actual image was *deleted from disk*. **However**, the `Picture` object is restored by the NSUndoManager and `filePath` is now set to an image that's *physically deleted*.

Is there a way to know when a Picture is **really** deleted (i.e. in prepareForDeletion:)? I mean, it was deleted by the user AND not brought back by an undo operation?

Should I really not delete anything and clean up the unlinked photo's from my app documents every x days? Or should I keep track of which `Picture`s the user deleted and queue them up for deletion when the user presses *save* instead of *cancel*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solved" this issue by just never deleting from disk by any user action, and to run a cleanup method every time the app starts.